# Python- how to allow only 1 thread to go through in a while

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, pthreads, python-multithreading

(Solved- used a flag and added a small sleep so it didnt repeat)I made a while loop that calls a thread to do an action if condition is true and once that action is complete it should mean that condition would no longer be true for some time. However since the while loop iterates so many times before the thread can complete I think it calls many threads to try to complete this action. I do not want to slow down the while.

I tried setting an event and clearing events and neither worked/ worked right as I do not know much about it.

Comment: So have the worker thread send an event / set a variable / *etc*. to indicate that it has finished, and don't start any new one until you see that it has done so.  That can also be your signal to join that thread without worrying about blocking.